# Name Already exist error for newly created tab using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to create VBA macro in excel where one excel sheet tracks a path and creates a new tab in another sheet. It works well but when I create another tab "accidentally" with same name it gives me error as "Name already taken try another one". I don't want to create one more tab with same name. Instead it should stop me from creating tabs with same name

Is there anyway if there that name already exist it gives me a pop up saying name already exist I get only one option as ok to click. I click Ok and the additional sheet that is created doesn't get saved (or if already created deletes itself or save as same name with (2) next to it as excel usually do for repeated sheets). I am trying something like this

```
If wb.ActiveSheet.Name = sName Then wb.ActiveSheet.Delete
```

Here is my code

```
Private Sub Filling_List()

Dim sPath As String
Dim sFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook

Dim sName As String 'add sName declaration

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("S0")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

sPath = "C:\Users\arp\Desktop\Filling list macro\"
sFile = sPath & "ArF Filling List.xlsm"

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFile)

wb.Worksheets("ArF Templete").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

sName = ws1.Range("A1") & " " & ws1.Range("T2")  

wb.ActiveSheet.Name = sName
```

'If wb.ActiveSheet.Name = sName Then wb.ActiveSheet.Delete  "I am trying this but it doesn't work"

```
If sName = vbNullString Then Exit Sub 'compare against vbNullstring not empty string literal

With wb.Worksheets(sName)

.Cells(3, "E") = InputBox("Your Initials:")
'.Cells(5, "E") = InputBox("Col?:")
.Cells(6, "E") = InputBox("I:")
.Cells(7, "E") = InputBox("ET1 B:")
.Range("B03") = wb1.Worksheets("Que").Range("B02").Value2
.Range("B04") = wb1.Worksheets("Que").Range("E01").Value2
.Range("B05") = wb1.Worksheets("Que").Range("B01").Value2
.Cells(3, "E") = wb1.Worksheets("Que").Range("E02").Value2
.Cells(5, "E") = "Yes"
'Filling order
.Range("B38:B43") = wb1.Worksheets("Que & Tsc Cal").Range("B04:B09").Value2
.Range("C38:C43") = wb1.Worksheets("Que & Tsc Cal").Range("C04:C09").Value2
.Range("D38:D43") = wb1.Worksheets("Que & Tsc Cal").Range("A04:A09").Value2

'Retains

End With


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I developed above version with the help of you guys here and joining bits and pieces from other threads.Any suggestions to make it better are very welcome.

Comment: Cyril's suggestion is a good one and you might consider implementing as a function so you can re-use in future code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [W]hen I create another tab "accidentally" with same name it gives me error . . . I don't want to create one more tab with same name. Instead it should stop me from creating tabs with same name

This is not an uncommon problem with macros that create tabs--it is easy to accidentally run them twice. To prevent this, first check to see if the tab already exists and only after verifying that it doesn't exist, call the `Worksheets.Copy` method.

```
Private Sub Filling_List()

Dim sPath As String
Dim sFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook

Dim sName As String 'add sName declaration

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("S0")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

sPath = "C:\Users\arp\Desktop\Filling list macro\"
sFile = sPath & "ArF Filling List.xlsm"

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFile)

sName = ws1.Range("A1") & " " & ws1.Range("T2")

On Error Resume Next
Dim wslTest As Worksheet
Set wslTest = wb.Worksheets(sName)
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Tab: " & sName & " already exists.", vbInformation
    wslTest.Activate
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0

wb.Worksheets("ArF Templete").Copy After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
wb.ActiveSheet.Name = sName


' rest of code


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Rachel. Very well explained and it works perfectly the way I want. I will test it couple more times.

Thank you once again. Cyril,Scott,silent revolution !!

Answer (score 6):

I use a check if the named tab/sheet is available:

```
If IsError(Evaluate("SHEETNAME!A1")) Then
    'Nothing
Else
    Sheets("SHEETNAME").Delete
End If
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "SHEETNAME"
```

Or as suggested by Scott to have it be simpler and cleaner:

```
If Not IsError(Evaluate("SHEETNAME!A1")) Then Sheets("SHEETNAME").Delete
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "SHEETNAME"
```

---

Edit 1:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If IsError(Evaluate("SHEETNAME!A1")) Then Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "SHEETNAME"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: @ScottCraner , it's a terrible answer, but it's the real one... i started doing this years ago when i first started learning VBA and have always just copied it forward and never corrected it.  All points you make are great and just made me giggle at something I've carried forward for no other reason that being too lazy to rewrite (it works, don't f with it, mentality).  Updating answer and some of my personal code... Thanks, as always!

Comment: I have a few of those also.

Comment: The OP doesn't want delete the existing tab. Instead, only add a tab if one with that name doesn't already exist.

Comment: @RachelHettinger Reading the code and the post, OP was trying what I have done with his line of code: 'If wb.ActiveSheet.Name = sName Then wb.ActiveSheet.Delete "I am trying this but it doesn't work"  In the text portion above his code he mentions a stop of sorts or acknowledging, so either or should be fine.  We could also modify the code in my answer to state when no error do nothing and if error (no sheet able to be evaluated) then you create the sheet.  Of my code, the final line would be the True section, then get rid of the Else.

Comment: Just because the OP is going down the rabbit hole doesn’t mean you have to follow him.

Comment: You guys are amazing.Thank you guys for the inputs
Cyril, After using this still give me he same error.Name already taken.
First time I create the new tab it works as I want.Second time with the same name it gives me Name already taken error.Can we prevent it from creating it second time if it sees same name already exist and end it and not give error.
I want it only once in the file with the specified name.I used delete function since when it gives me error it create the tab halfway using template name and leaves it there,I wanted to delete that tabs so we dont have lot of not needed tabs)

Comment: @Eric This should be intentionally causing/checking an error, and the if-statement does one thing or another (true-case, false-case) based on that condition.  You may want to use Application.DisplayAlerts = False before the If statement and Application.DisplayAlerts = True after, to turn the alerts back on.  See the update to the code (Edit 1) for a code which prevents creating a new sheet if the one you want exists.

Answer (score 1):

The code below should do what you want, you may need to adapt it for your project.

```
Option Explicit

Sub addsheet()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.add

    On Error Resume Next                                    'Prevent Excel from stopping on an error but just goes to next line
    ws.Name = "Sheet1"

    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet with this name already exists"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False                   'Prevent confirmation popup on sheet deletion
        ws.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True                    'Turn alerts back on
        On Error GoTo 0                                     'Stop excel from skipping errors
        Exit Sub                                            'Terminate sub after a failed attempt to add sheet
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0                                         'Stop Excel from skipping errors.

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the point of `Exit Sub` when you have nothing to detour from?

Comment: @JohnyL, In this particular sub nothing. But one  could imagine more code after the check which would be undesirable to execute if there was no new sheet added.

Comment: Thank you very much Silent revolution. I see this code works and doesn't give me any error. But it doesn't delete the sheet that is created. every time I hit the tab it creates a new sheet with template names "ArF Templete (2), ArF templete(3), (4) and so on. I guess
     `ws.delete` 
doesnt work and I have lot of tabs that I are just halfway created (tab created with format but data don't transfer i guess it end at end if) and didnt get delete. 
Can you help me with that?

Comment: I also do not see.
    `MsgBox "Worksheet with this name already exists"`

I used part of your code from  


    `On Error Resume Next`    
    `ws.Name = "Sheet1"`

   `If Err.Number = 1004 Then`
        `MsgBox "Worksheet with this name already exists"`
        `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`
        `ws.Delete`
        `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`
        `On Error GoTo 0`
        `Exit Sub`                                            
    `End If `

I used in just after the first part of my code (in my question post ). and before the second part.